# Best practise re-init JS after re-render component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, materialize

I am currently using the following workaround to re-init JS code like Materialize and Bootstrap for accordions, etc. after a re-rendering of the component. Now I have the problem that the component is re-rendered for each accordion item one time and I don't want to run the init code for each item again.

What is the best practise to wait for the last render routine to be finished after props/state have changed?

```
class List extends Component {

constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {
        collapsibleIsMounted: false
    };
}

componentDidMount() {

    this.initializeCollapsible();
}

componentDidUpdate() {

    this.initializeCollapsible();
}

initializeCollapsible() {

    const collapsibleExists = $('.collapsible').length > 0;
    const isMounted = this.state.collapsibleIsMounted;

    if( collapsibleExists && !isMounted ) {

        $('.collapsible').collapsible({
            accordion: false
        });
        this.setState({
            collapsibleIsMounted: true
        });
    }
}

componentWillMount() {

    this.props.fetchItems();
}
```

Here the render routines:

```
render() {

    const {items} = this.props

    return(
        <ul className="collapsible popout" data-collapsible="expandable">
            {this.renderItems(items)}
        </ul>
    );
}

renderItems(items) {
    return items.map((item) => {

        return (
            <li key={item.id}>
                <div className="collapsible-header">{item.title}</div>
                <div className="collapsible-body"><p>Test</p></div>
            </li>
        );
    });
}
```

One possible solution to solve the problem is as follows, but I was hoping that there is a better solution (maybe using redux) as it is a "huge" amount of code for the small functionality and it somehow feels wrong:

```
initializeCollapsible() {

    const collapsibleExists = $('.project-list .collapsible').length > 0;
    const isMounted = this.state.collapsibleIsMounted;
    const amountItems = $('.project-list .collapsible li').length;

    if( collapsibleExists && !isMounted && amountItems > 0 ) {

        $('.ppp .collapsible').collapsible({
            accordion: false
        });
        this.setState({
            collapsibleIsMounted: true
        });
    }
}
```